# What's the best way to provide interface to these library functions?

Tags: java, design-patterns, method-reference, functional-interface

I'm building a library package, which has an interface `PropTransformer` which will be implemented by 30+ classes. I'm taking one such class here say `ShapeTransformer`

```
public interface PropTransformer<T, R> {
    R transform(T t);
    T reverseTransform(R r);
}
```

```
public class ShapeTransformer implements PropTransformer<List<String>, Set<String>> {
    
    @Override
    public Set<String> transform(final List<String> list) {
        // transform code
    }

    @Override
    public List<String> reverseTransform(final Set<String> set) {
        // reverseTransform code
    }
}
```

This library's classes methods can be invoked using `new` operator obviously, but since a lot of transformations can be done on user side so a lot of instantiation will appear bloated. Something like:

```
new ShapeTransformer().transform(...); 
new TemperatureTransformer().transform(...);
...
```

I could think of creating a utility class `Transformer` which would provide a direct invocation for transformers, like

```
public class Transformer<T, R> {

    private static ShapeTransformer shapeTransformer = new CompatibleDevicesTransformer();

    public static Set<String> shapeTransform(final List<String> list) {
        return shapeTransformer.transform(list);
    }

    public static List<String> shapeReverseTransform(final Set<String> set) {
        return shapeTransformer.reverseTransform(set);
    }
}
```

Library user can then use it like

```
Transformer.shapeTransform(...)
```

Problems with this approach:

- It won't scale as Transformer class will keep growing with number of transformers that implement `PropTransformer`.
- Kind of repeat work is being done by adding static methods and variables in `Transformer` class

Is there a cleaner/better way to accomplish this? Through method reference(s) and/or functional interface(s), if possible?

Something like

```
Transformer t = new Transformer();
t.transform(ShapeTransformer::transform);
t.transform(TemperatureTransformer::transform);
```

(^ this is just to provide a peek into what I'm looking for. I'm not necessarily suggesting to make the transformers method static)

Comment: Is the client code free to use any of the `PropTransformer` implementations or does it depend on some attribute?

Comment: @Smile All implementations are independent of each other. Client is free to and can use any number of implementations. The only reason the implementations are implementing the same interface is to maintain a contract of being a transformer. Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PropTransformer` is not a functional interface as it contains more than 1 abstract method. So, you can't implement and call these methods using lamda expression.

You can split `PropTransformer` into functional interfaces `PropTransformer` and `PropReverseTransformer.` But decision should be based on how `PropTransformer` fit into overall design.

To further reduce boilerplate code at client side, you can create `PropTransformerFactory` - a utility to create `PropTransformer` implementations.
Pseudo Code:

```java
public class PropTransformerFactory {
    public static PropTransformer createShapeTransformer() {
        return new ShapeTransformer();
    }

    public static PropTransformer createTemperatureTransformer() {
        return new TemperatureTransformer();
    }
}
```